# Spring boot application testing service + repository together

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I need to write an integration test for the service together with the repository. I find challenging for building a sliced context that contains the service and the repositories beans.

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop")
public class MessageRouterDestinationsTest {
```

With this configuration I was able to setup the repositories against an in memory datasource. I expect to add the services beans and everything to be in place.
I have added

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MessageRouterService.class})
```

but I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages
```

My full configuration now is:

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MessageRouterService.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MessageRouterDestinationsTest {

@Autowired
    private MessageRouterService messageRouterService;
.....
```

However, now I receive

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.. for the repository bean.
```

My question are?

1. Does `@ContextConfiguration` disable `@DataJpaTest`?
2. What is the cause of

   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base
   packages
3. What is the best way to configure a SpringContext with repositories + services?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a single class for your sliced test, you can use `@Import(NameOfClass.class)` and then remove `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MessageRouterService.class})` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from your test class.

Be aware that with that your test context now expects all beans that the `MessageRouterService` depends on. Either mock them with `@MockBean` or also import them (potentially ending in a never-ending import of dependent beans).